# How to remove inner text of HTML tag with HTML tag from a string using regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

My String is given below ,

```
var str = "The test <del> SString </del> string , The other <del>textt </del> test&nbsp; string, <br/>  show &nbsp; something";
```

I can write regex pattern which is removed only html tag , pattern is given below,

```
pattern = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig
```

In Str Variable, there can be any html tag like as bold tag(b), italic tag(i).... etc.

How to write regex pattern in jquery or javascript which will be remove inner text of html tag with html tag.

Actually the result will be,

**"The test string , the other test string , show something"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it ***Lazy***

```
<([^>]+)>.*?<\/\1>|<.*?\/>
```

Here is [demo](http://regex101.com/r/wC5vM7/3)

sample code:

```
var re = /<([^>]+)>.*?<\/\1>|<.*?\/>/g;
var str = 'The test <del> SString </del> string , The other <del>textt </del> test&nbsp; string, <br/> show $nbsp; something\n\nThe test string , the other test string , show something';

var result = str.replace(re, '');
```

---

*EDIT*

Note: The above regex does not support tags having attributes.

Try below regex to cover any attributes having in tag. Here is the [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wC5vM7/25)

```
<([^( |>)]+)([^>]*)>.*?<\/\1>|<.*?\/>
```

Comment: Your pattern is good. Could You remove &nbsp; (space) from string using regex with your pattern.

Comment: just add it in the regex pattern `&nbsp;` for example `<([^>]+)>.*?<\/\1>|<.*?\/>|&nbsp;`

Comment: My element text contains also style defination like: <h1 style=color:red>Hi</h1>, the regex not support it, could you help with better regex?

Comment: the above regex mentioned in answer `<([^>]+)>.*?<\/\1>|<.*?\/>` is made as per user case. Right now it supports only tags without and attribute hence it's not working in your case.

Comment: Here is the [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wC5vM7/25) to solve your use case using regex `<([^( |>)]+)([^>]*)>.*?<\/\1>|<.*?\/>`

Answer (score 1):

This would work.

```
var str = "The test <del> SString </del> string , The other <del>textt </del> test&nbsp; string, <br/>  show $nbsp; something";
$a = $('<div>'+str+'</div>');
$a.children().remove()
var whatYouWant = $a.text();
```

Answer (score 1):

Following Function will help you,

```
function getChildText(node) {
    var text = "";
    for (var child = node.firstChild; !! child; child = child.nextSibling) {
        if (child.nodeType === 3) {
            text += child.nodeValue;
        }
    }
    return text;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jvqdokrf/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "The test <del> SString </del> string , The other <del>textt </del> test&nbsp; string, <br/>  show $nbsp; something";
```

What you want

```
$("<div>"+str+"</div>").text()
//result retun is: "The test  SString  string , The other textt  test  string,   show $nbsp; something"
```

Comment: How is possible? Please check the code and let me khow. Here Only will be remove HTML Tag. I need remove inner text of HTML tag with HTML tag.

Comment: The test  SString  string , The other textt  test  string,   show $nbsp; something" is what you want?